# Overriding __init__ with parent classmethod in python

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, class-method

I want to do something like the following (in Python 3.7):

```
class Animal:

    def __init__(self, name, legs):
        self.legs = legs
        print(name)

    @classmethod 
    def with_two_legs(cls, name):
        # extremely long code to generate name_full from name
        name_full = name
        return cls(name_full, 2)

class Human(Animal):

    def __init__(self):
        super().with_two_legs('Human')

john = Human()
```

Basically, I want to override the `__init__` method of a child class with a factory classmethod of the parent. The code as written, however, does not work, and raises:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

I think this means that `super().with_two_legs('Human')` passes `Human` as the `cls` variable.

1) Why doesn't this work as written? I assumed `super()` would return a proxy instance of the superclass, so `cls` would be `Animal` right?

2) Even if this was the case I don't think this code achieves what I want, since the classmethod returns an instance of `Animal`, but I just want to initialize `Human` in the same way classmethod does, is there any way to achieve the behaviour I want?

I hope this is not a very obvious question, I found the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) on `super()` somewhat confusing.

Comment: you should say:  `super('Human', 2)` as that is the constructor for animal.  Then you dont need to use the static method defined in Animal, which kinda feels like it shouldnt belong.

Comment: Use ```Animal.with_two_legs()``` rather than ```super().with_two_legs()```.

Comment: You are breaking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle because `Human.__init__` has different signature than `Animal.__init__`

Comment: your code doesn't give this error. You put wrong code or wrong error message.

Comment: If you put in `print(cls)` as the first line of `with_two_legs` you will see that the assumption in 1) was incorrect.

Comment: The whole point of using the classmethod is to have an *alternative* to `__init__`. So to create your instance, use the alternative constructor: `human = Human.with_two_legs("Human")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`super().with_two_legs('Human')` does in fact call `Animal`'s `with_two_legs`, but it passes `Human` as the `cls`, not `Animal`. `super()` makes the proxy object only to assist with method lookup, it doesn't change what gets passed (it's still the same `self` or `cls` it originated from). In this case, `super()` isn't even doing anything useful, because `Human` doesn't override `with_two_legs`, so:

```
super().with_two_legs('Human')
```

means "call `with_two_legs` from the first class above `Human` in the hierarchy which defines it", and:

```
cls.with_two_legs('Human')
```

means "call `with_two_legs` on the first class in the hierarchy starting with `cls` that defines it". As long as no class below `Animal` defines it, those do the same thing.

This means your code breaks at `return cls(name_full, 2)`, because `cls` is still `Human`, and your `Human.__init__` doesn't take any arguments beyond `self`. Even if you futzed around to make it work (e.g. by adding two optional arguments that you ignore), this would cause an infinite loop, as `Human.__init__` called `Animal.with_two_legs`, which in turn tried to construct a `Human`, calling `Human.__init__` again.

What you're trying to do is not a great idea; alternate constructors, by their nature, depend on the core constructor/initializer for the class. If you try to make a core constructor/initializer that relies on an alternate constructor, you've created a circular dependency.

In this particular case, I'd recommend avoiding the alternate constructor, in favor of either explicitly providing the `legs` count always, or using an intermediate `TwoLeggedAnimal` class that performs the task of your alternate constructor. If you want to reuse code, the second option just means your "extremely long code to generate name_full from name" can go in `TwoLeggedAnimal`'s `__init__`; in the first option, you'd just write a `staticmethod` that factors out that code so it can be used by both `with_two_legs` and other constructors that need to use it.

The class hierarchy would look something like:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, legs):
        self.legs = legs
        print(name)

class TwoLeggedAnimal(Animal)
    def __init__(self, name):
        # extremely long code to generate name_full from name
        name_full = name
        super().__init__(name_full, 2)

class Human(TwoLeggedAnimal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Human')
```

The common code approach would instead be something like:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, legs):
        self.legs = legs
        print(name)

    @staticmethod
    def _make_two_legged_name(basename):
        # extremely long code to generate name_full from name
        return name_full

    @classmethod 
    def with_two_legs(cls, name):
        return cls(cls._make_two_legged_name(name), 2)

class Human(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self._make_two_legged_name('Human'), 2)
```

---

Side-note: What you were trying to do wouldn't work even if you worked around the recursion, because `__init__` doesn't *make* new instances, it initializes existing instances. So even if you call `super().with_two_legs('Human')` and it somehow works, it's making and returning a completely different instance, but not doing anything to the `self` received by `__init__` which is what's actually being created. The best you'd have been able to do is something like:

```
def __init__(self):
    self_template = super().with_two_legs('Human')
    # Cheaty way to copy all attributes from self_template to self, assuming no use
    # of __slots__
    vars(self).update(vars(self_template))
```

There is no way to call an alternate constructor in `__init__` and have it change `self` implicitly. About the only way I can think of to make this work in the way you intended without creating helper methods and preserving your alternate constructor would be to use `__new__` instead of `__init__` (so you can return an instance created by another constructor), and doing awful things with the alternate constructor to explicitly call the top class's `__new__` to avoid circular calling dependencies:

```
class Animal:
    def __new__(cls, name, legs):  # Use __new__ instead of __init__
        self = super().__new__(cls)  # Constructs base object
        self.legs = legs
        print(name)
        return self  # Returns initialized object
    @classmethod
    def with_two_legs(cls, name):
        # extremely long code to generate name_full from name
        name_full = name
        return Animal.__new__(cls, name_full, 2)  # Explicitly call Animal's __new__ using correct subclass

class Human(Animal):
    def __new__(cls):
        return super().with_two_legs('Human')  # Return result of alternate constructor
```

Comment: "(...)you'd just write a staticmethod that factors out that code so it can be used by both with_two_legs and other constructors that need to use it. (...)". This is exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

The proxy object you get from calling `super` was only used to locate the `with_two_legs` method to be called (and since you didn't override it in `Human`, you could have used `self.with_two_legs` for the same result).

As [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim) commented, your alternative constructor `with_two_legs` doesn't work because the `Human` class breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) by having a different constructor signature. Even if you could get the code to call `Animal` to build your instance, you'd have problems because you'd end up with an `Animal` instances and not a `Human` one (so other methods in `Human`, if you wrote some, would not be available).

Note that this situation is not that uncommon, many Python subclasses have different constructor signatures than their parent classes. But it does mean that you can't use one class freely in place of the other, as happens with a `classmethod` that tries to construct instances. You need to avoid those situations.

In this case, you are probably best served by using a default value for the `legs` argument to the `Animal` constructor. It can default to `2` legs if no alternative number is passed. Then you don't need the `classmethod`, and you don't run into problems when you override `__init__`:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, legs=2): # legs is now optional, defaults to 2
        self.legs = legs
        print(name)

class Human(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Human')

john = Human()
```

Comment: I understand that there are possibly better ways to design these classes. The problem is that the classmethod is part of a public API that can't really be changed at this stage, along with many other things, but the instance that gets built through this method is specific enough that it merits its own class. My current solution was  similar to what you did but I wrapped all the long code inside a ```staticmethod``` and I called that static method both in the constructor of Human and the classmethod of Animal.